# Files are not found although they exist

Tags: python, subprocess, python-imaging-library

I have this Python code:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw
import subprocess
import shlex

font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-C.ttf", 66)
text = "me@example.com"
size = font.getsize(text)

img = Image.new('RGBA', size=size, color=(0, 0, 0, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((0, 0), text, fill=(209, 239, 8), font=font)

img.save('/home/alex/label.jpg')

cmd = 'composite -dissolve 25% -gravity south /home/alex/label.jpg /home/alex/in.jpg /home/alex/out1.jpg'
proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd))
proc.communicate()
```

`label.jpg` and `in.jpg` exist, `out1.jpg`, obviously, not. But I always get the error:

```
    proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What's up with this?

Comment: Are you sure that `composite` is in the path?

Comment: @Carsten. It worked for sure. But I think it worked only before I updated the system. Now it says `The program 'composite' can be found in the following packages:
 * imagemagick
 * graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>` Which one should I install?

Comment: Depends. Which program do you want to install? ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the PATH, try specifying the full path for **composite**